# How to display parent and child in html table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an SQL table with (id,name,parentid) fields like following:

```
Id      Name                ParentId

1       Musical Instrument      0

2       Classical               1

3       Guitar                  2

4       Piano                   2

5       Western                 1

6       Drums                   5

7       Trumpet                 5

8       Trumpet A               7

9       Trumpet B               7
```

How could I display this in a table view using ASP.NET MVC 4 with a recursive function?

Comment: And ? Where is the blocking part ?

Comment: What have you tried?  We need more information.  Can you add a code sample?

Comment: Yes please can you put your code here ...?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you pulled it table using entity framework

```
var myTable = dbcontext.instruments.Include(t=>t.parentId).toList();
```

You send this myTable as the model to your view and loop over it using foreach loop.